# Asking user to enter values in cmd instead of taking from different file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have `batch` file which accepts param, as of now I am taking param from another text file `ClientName.txt`.

Now I need to take param from cmd itself like *Enter client name:*. See my file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in (1.ClientName.txt) DO ( 
XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%%A\drawable\*" "..\Global\Resources\" /E /F /R /Y /H   >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%%A\SplashSc\*" "..\Global\Resources\" /E /F /R /Y /H   >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
)
```

How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you change the syntax of your `for /F` loop in the altered code? Type `for /?` to learn how to use that command...

Comment: @aschipfl - As I know I didn't change code of `for/f`. I just kept `%$Client%` insted of `(1.ClientName.txt)`.

Comment: Well, you did change something: you removed parentheses and you added line-breaks. Anyway, since you edited the question I think you don't even need a `for /F` loop, you could use `%$Client%` directly in your `xcopy` paths (instead of `%%A`). To ensure the given path actually exists you could insert [`if exist`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)`"..\AppIcons\%$Client%\" goto :EOF`...

Comment: Why do you `enabledelayedexpansion`? Are you using it anywhere else in the script? if not, it is not needed here. Also, you could do this without the for loop.

Comment: It is not a common practice to start variable names with a `'$'` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of above comments I got answer

```
@echo off
    set /p $client=Enter project name:

        XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%$client%\drawable-hdpi\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable-hdpi\" /E /F /R /Y /H            >> "..\AppIcons\%$client%\copy.log"
        XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%$client%\drawable-mdpi\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable-mdpi\" /E /F /R /Y /H            >> "..\AppIcons\%$client%\copy.log"
        XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%$client%\drawable-xhdpi\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable-xhdpi\" /E /F /R /Y /H          >> "..\AppIcons\%$client%\copy.log"
        XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%$client%\GoogleJsonFile\*" "..\RisingSun\" /E /F /R /Y /H       >> "..\AppIcons\%$client%\copy.log"
        XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%$client%\LoginPageImage\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable\" /E /F /R /Y /H        >> "..\AppIcons\%$client%\copy.log"
        XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%$client%\MenifestFile\*" "..\RisingSun\Properties\" /E /F /R /Y /H          >> "..\AppIcons\%$client%\copy.log"
        XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%$client%\SplashScreenImage\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable\" /E /F /R /Y /H      >> "..\AppIcons\%$client%\copy.log"
```